# Firefox - сохранение данных форм

Tags: javascript, html

Авторизация происходит через обычную форму с установленными атрибутами:

```
method="POST" onsubmit="make(); return false;"
```

Сначала AJAX'ом, проверю правильность данных, произвожу авторизацию пользователя, возвращаю соответствующий код, на клиенте произвожу редирект. Таким образом форма предлагает мне сохранить данные формы после правильного ввода. В хроме все хорошо работает, то есть пароль предлагается сохранить только после правильного ввода (как и нужно), а Firefox предлагает по `submit` у формы, то есть предлагает сохранить форму в холостою.

Не понятно то, что я прервал сабмит формы, и ни какие данные не должны передаваться (`onsubmit="make();`**`return false;`**`"`) но все равно Firefox предлагает сохранить форму. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть в Firefox функция `make` приводит к ошибке, и поэтому `return false` не выполняется.

Можно использовать `event.preventDefault()`, чтобы данные не передавались, даже если будут ошибки:

```js
function make(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Привет");
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="make(event);">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```